# Translate Python code to C# equivalent

Tags: c#, python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to rewrite the python code example from the book to C# equivalent in order to test its functionality.

The code is the following:

```
q = "select target_id from connection where source_id=me() and target_type='user'"
my_friends = [str(t['target_id']) for t in fql.query(q)]

q = "select uid1, uid2 from friends where uid1 in (%s) and iud2 in (%s)" %
    (",".join(my_friends), ",".join(my_friends),)
mutual_friendships = fql(q)
```

What I don't know is sign `%s` and what `(%s)` in code means. I would really appreciate if anyone could write the equivalent code in C#.

Comment: What is `fql`? `%s` is just replaced with appropriate string made from the value that is passed in the corresponding position after `%` operator (the one that separates string from tuple).

Comment: in the python code, I would suggest you to use `.format()` instead of `%`, because you are making the `join` method two times. `'{0} ... {0}'.format(",".join(my_friends))` is waaaay better

Comment: sorry @jamesTheProgrammer, but you're completely wrong. Check the answers to see what `%` does in **python**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### String formatting operation in Python

`%s` are replaced with the corresponding values from the tuple passed after `%` operator.

### How it works in Python

For example this:

```
my_friends = [0, 2, 666, 123132]
print "select uid1 from friends where uid1 in (%s)" % (",".join(my_friends))
```

would print this:

> select uid1 from friends where uid1 in (0,2,666,123132)

### How to replace it with C#

You need to use `String.Format()`, as mentioned eg. here: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

```
string formatString = "select uid1, uid2 from friends where uid1 in ({0}) and iud2 in ({1})"
string q = String.Format(formatString, yourReplacement1, yourReplacement2)
```

It works the way that is very similar to Python's string `format()` method (available since Python 2.6).

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` are replacement placeholders for string formatting, which would be equivalent to `{0}...{1}` and so on when calling `String.Format()` or a similar function in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
string.Format("select uid1, uid2 from friends where uid1 in ({0}) and iud2 in ({1})",
              <value for {0}>, 
              <value for {1}>);
```

The `%s` would translate to a `{0}...{N}` for any string values.  `%d`, et al, would all be represented in the `{0}...{N}` syntax as well but there are several different Format Strings defined on MSDN.  For example, there are [Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Date Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).